# Uniform Convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{x}{i^2}\right)$ and its differentiabilty

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence

I was trying to prove it is uniform convergent by it is Cauchy in sup-norm,
since I don't know what does it converge to and it seems that M-test fail (as each term is bounded by $\pi/2$).

$\left\|\sum_{i=n+1}^m\arctan\left(\frac{x}{i^2}\right)\right\|$, then I dont know how to continue.

But I know it is pointwisely convergent.

Then, I differentiate it term by term, i get $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{i^4}+1}$. Then I find that when $x=0$, it becomes $1+1+1+1+...$ which is divergent, but the question says $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{x}{i^2}\right)$ is differentiable.

Why does it happen?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What range of $x$ are you considering?

Comment: @πr8  it should be on the whole real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M-test works if you're working on a bounded interval - just need that $\vert \arctan x \vert \le \vert x \vert$ and that $\sum_i \frac{1}{i^2}$ is convergent.

A tidy proof of this for $x>0$ comes from the following:

$$0\le\frac{1}{1+t^2}\le1\implies0\le\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt\le\int_0^x1dt\implies0\le\arctan x\le x$$

and an entirely analogous proof works for $x<0$ as well.

If you're on an unbounded interval, the convergence isn't uniform - note that:

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert\sum_{n\ge N} \arctan \frac{x}{n^2}\vert\ge\arctan\frac{N^2}{N^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

which shows that the sum is not Cauchy.

Furthermore, for your differentiation, you're missing a term from the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan\frac{x}{i^2}=\frac{1}{i^2}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x}{i^2}\right)^2}=\frac{i^2}{x^2+i^4}$$

Comment: Thank you very much,  I was so careless ;(

Answer (score 2):

For starters,
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\arctan\frac{x}{k^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{k^2}}{1+\left(\frac{x}{k^2}\right)^2} =\frac{1}{k^2+\frac{x^2}{k^2}}$$
and for $x\to 0$
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$
Moreover, by the AM-GM inequality
$$ \frac{1}{k^2+\frac{x^2}{k^2}}=\frac{1}{\frac{k^2}{2}+\frac{k^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{k^2}}\leq \frac{2}{k^2+|x|\sqrt{8}} $$
and for any $A\in\mathbb{R}^+$:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2+A^2}=\frac{-1+\pi A\coth(\pi A)}{2A^2}.$$
So it is not difficult to prove the pointwise convergence of the series of the derivatives to a continuous function, by studying it first on $[0,1]$ then on $(1,+\infty)$.
Also notice that
$$ \prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{ix}{k^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
is a convergent product, since $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2 x}{6}$, and
$$ \sum_{k\ge 1}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{k^2}\right) $$
is trivially related with the [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29) of $(1)$.

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you just bound $\frac{1}{k^2+\frac{x^2}{k^2}}$ by $\frac{1}{k^2}$, which you've already shown is summable?

Comment: @πr8: because I wanted to grasp better the behaviour at $+\infty$. That bound with a $\coth$ describes it better.

Comment: Gotcha, I can see why that might be useful in understanding the function's behaviour. I do like the $\coth$ series but it does seem a little less than elementary for a question like this.

Comment: @πr8: you are probably right, but I have added another simple (sketch of) proof through an infinite product.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank tou for your reply. I need to apologize to you, as πr8 and you both give me great ideas for solving my problem, but it seems that πr8 is the first one who answered my question, but I am really interested in your reply, so may I answer is $$\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{k^2+A^2} = \frac{-1+\pi A Coth(\pi A)}{2A^2}$$  a fact? And how the infinite product relates my question?

Comment: @JoeHo: that is a well-known series that can be proved through Fourier series or Weierstrass products. The infinite product is related with your series just because $\arctan\frac{x}{k^2}$ is the argument of $1+\frac{ix}{k^2}$. Since the infinite product is convergent and well-behaved, so it has to be your series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And why that infinite product converges? Is it because of some other facts?

Comment: @JoeHo: yes, a well-known lemma. If $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n$ converges, so does $\prod_{n\geq 1} (1+a_n)$.